# How to limit disk space of local TFS/VSTS build agent?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015, build-agent

Currently my team is using local build agents for our on-premise TFS 2015 installation. We've installed these build agents on our own development machines. However we are having issues limiting the space required for the continuous integration builds.

Our disk space is limited. Consequently we have to remove old build tasks (including sources and artifacts) manually to clean-up disk space.

Is there some way to automate this? Preferly by telling TFS to automatically remove older build tasks.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can [specify build retention policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/build/define/retention), which will automatically delete old completed builds to minimize clutter. You modify these policies on the **Retention** tab of your build definition. Retention policies will delete the items below:

   - The build record
   - Logs
   - Published artifacts
   - Automated test results
   - Published artifacts
   - Published symbols
2. Currentlt, server drops are deleted when a build is deleted but drops to UNC shares are not. **This has been fixed on Team Services and is in Team Foundation Server '15', which is currently in prerelease**. Check: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1513256/build-preview-drop-folder-not-deleted-when-build-is-deleted
3. Working folder on your machine won't be deleted . In order to delete UNC drops and working folder, you can add a task [**Delete files**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/delete-files) in your build definition to delete working folder and drop folder.

Comment: Nice overview and it looks like option number three is the best solution for our case.

Comment: this was long time ago, does this still hold? i cannot set agent limit for workdir? what happens when the disk space is over?